# I want to access previous node output in .html file of current node in custom nodes of node-red

Tags: node-red

I want to access previous node output in .html file of current node in custom nodes of node-red,how?Can someone give me an idea?

Previous node output can be accessed in current node .js file can it be accessed in .html file as well?
OR

How to pass data from .js file to .html file of a custom node?

Comment: You need to explain in a lot more detail what you are trying to do, But it is worth noting that a Node should not care what other nodes it is connected to. Also the `.js` is runtime and the `.html` file is for the config only.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to make runtime custom node data available to the admin interface (the html file) is to create a new ExpressJS endpoint to use as an API.

Check out the code for the build-in serial node which does this.